# Does an Android Wifi P2p (Wifi Direct) connection work across Activities?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am trying to add Wifi Direct functionality to an existing app to send data and files to a server running on Windows.

The app already has several Activities that communicate with a server and copy files in the background and I am trying to figure out how this will work with WifiP2p connections.

If I connect to another device with Wifi Direct what happens when the apps Activity changes?  Does the connection persist and if so how do I get the connection information in another Activity?

I don't want to have to reconnect in every Activity that needs to send data.  All the examples I've seen are single activity and only for Android to Android connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that WiFi P2P connections act in a similar way to regular WiFi connections to an access point.  The connection appears to persist even after the app has been terminated and there is a connection indicator in the top bar next to the wifi icon.

This makes some sense and you can make a WiFi Direct connection through the settings on some devices.  I have a Galaxy Camera (EK-GC110, Android 4.1.2) which has this ability in the settings but my other device does NOT (Galaxy Tab A, Android 5.0.2).  Both work fine with the WiFiDirectDemo.

This behavior was not obvious to me from the documentation but maybe I missed something.  Nothing better than actually testing something with real devices.  Very annoying that I have to find 2 devices and load the demo app to figure this kind of thing out.